# Trying to use woocommerce commands on wp-cli - getting `'wc' is not a registered wp command.`

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wp-cli

I am working on an ubuntu machine and have installed the wp-cli globally using the official installation instructions. However, I can't run any woocommerce commands. They all trigger the same error:

`Error: 'wc' is not a registered wp command.`

this is the result of my `wp cli` command:

```
OS:     Linux 4.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/bash
PHP binary:     /usr/bin/php
PHP version:    7.2.16-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
php.ini used:   /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        /home/officedev/.composer/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:      /home/officedev/.composer/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:
WP-CLI packages dir:    /home/officedev/.wp-cli/packages/
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 2.1.0
```

Can someone help me see what is missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My apologies all, I somehow didn't realize that I didn't have the woocommerce plugin activated. The wp wc command only gets added to the wp cli if this is the case.

Comment: This also happens on a network where subsites have WooCommerce activated but the parent site doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install ***and activate*** the plugin...

```
$ wp wc
Error: 'wc' is not a registered wp command. See 'wp help' for available commands.
Did you mean 'db'?
$ wp plugin install woocommerce
...
$
$ wp wc
Error: 'wc' is not a registered wp command. See 'wp help' for available commands.
Did you mean 'db'?
$
$ wp plugin  activate woocommerce
Plugin 'woocommerce' activated.
Success: Activated 1 of 1 plugins.
$ wp wc
usage: wp wc customer <command>
   or: wp wc customer_download <command>
   or: wp wc order_note <command>
   or: wp wc payment_gateway <command>
   or: wp wc product <command>
   or: wp wc product_attribute <command>
   or: wp wc product_attribute_term <command>
   or: wp wc product_cat <command>
   or: wp wc product_review <command>
   or: wp wc product_shipping_class <command>
   or: wp wc product_tag <command>
   or: wp wc product_variation <command>
   or: wp wc shipping_method <command>
   or: wp wc shipping_zone <command>
   or: wp wc shipping_zone_location <command>
   or: wp wc shipping_zone_method <command>
   or: wp wc shop_coupon <command>
   or: wp wc shop_order <command>
   or: wp wc shop_order_refund <command>
   or: wp wc tax <command>
   or: wp wc tax_class <command>
   or: wp wc tool <command>
   or: wp wc tracker <command>
   or: wp wc update
   or: wp wc webhook <command>
   or: wp wc webhook_delivery <command>

See 'wp help wc <command>' for more information on a specific command.
$
```